# Bottom margin not respected with tikz and verticaly centered boxes

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes

I've been working on making a Cards Against Humanity clone in TeX and have everything but this one last bit working. The text on one card is long enough that I need to stick the logo/game name on the same line as the PICK (2) line. I make this work by adding it to the centered boxes with an `\hfill`. This almost works, except it drops the entire line down below the magin and not aligned with all the other cards. If I remove the tikz circle thingy, it works fine. How can I fix this?

Output: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3IwI7ioPGAJTk45RW1lMVBHOTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Code:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6.9596cm,paperheight=9.4996cm,margin=7.25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{color}

\linespread{1.4}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,fill,inner sep=2pt] (char) {\color{black} #1};}}
\newcommand*{\vcenteredhbox}[1]{\begingroup\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\parbox{\wd0}{\box0}\endgroup}
\newenvironment{bottompar}{\par\vspace*{\fill}}{\clearpage}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{draw}
\newcounter{pick}
\newcounter{small}
\define@key{card}{draw}[0]{\setcounter{draw}{#1}}
\define@key{card}{pick}[0]{\setcounter{pick}{#1}}
\define@key{card}{small}[0]{\setcounter{small}{#1}}
\savekeys{card}{draw, pick, small}
\presetkeys{card}{draw=0, pick=0, small=0}{}
\newcommand*\card[2][]{
\setkeys{card}{#1}
\raggedright
{
    \fontsize{15pt}{1em}\selectfont #2
}
\begin{bottompar}
\ifnum \thesmall>0
\vcenteredhbox{\includegraphics{derpy}}
\vcenteredhbox{
    \fontsize{8.5pt}{1em}\selectfont CAE
}
\hfill
{
\ifnum \thedraw>0
DRAW \circled{\thedraw}\\
\fi
\ifnum \thepick>0
PICK \circled{\thepick}\\
\fi
}
\else
{\raggedleft
\ifnum \thedraw>0
DRAW \circled{\thedraw}\\
\fi
\ifnum \thepick>0
PICK \circled{\thepick}\\
\fi
}
\vcenteredhbox{\includegraphics{derpy}}
\vcenteredhbox{
    \fontsize{8.5pt}{1em}\selectfont Cards Against Equestria
}
\fi
\end{bottompar}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setmainfont{HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd}
\card{Zecora’s meth lab.}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}
\card[small=1, pick=2]{Today, Mayor Mare announced her official campaign position on \rule{50mm}{1pt} and \rule{50mm}{1pt}. No pony was the least bit surprised.}
\card{Twilight botched another spell… it’s started raining \rule{50mm}{1pt}.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the newline `\\` after each `DRAW`/`PICK` command solves the bottom margin issue.

I also changed `CAE` to `CAE\vphantom{q}` so that the short form `CAE` has the same apparent height to `\vcenteredhbox` as does `Cards Against Equestria`. This fixes a slight alignment discrepancy I noticed.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6.9596cm,paperheight=9.4996cm,margin=7.25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\linespread{1.4}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,fill,inner sep=2pt,text=black] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand*{\vcenteredhbox}[1]{\begingroup\setbox0=\hbox{#1}\parbox{\wd0}{\box0}\endgroup}
\newenvironment{bottompar}{\par\vspace*{\fill}}{\clearpage}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{draw}
\newcounter{pick}
\newcounter{small}
\define@key{card}{draw}[0]{\setcounter{draw}{#1}}
\define@key{card}{pick}[0]{\setcounter{pick}{#1}}
\define@key{card}{small}[0]{\setcounter{small}{#1}}
\savekeys{card}{draw, pick, small}
\presetkeys{card}{draw=0, pick=0, small=0}{}
\newcommand*\card[2][]{
\setkeys{card}{#1}
\raggedright
{
    \fontsize{15pt}{1em}\selectfont #2
}
\begin{bottompar}
\ifnum \thesmall>0
\vcenteredhbox{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}
\vcenteredhbox{
    \fontsize{8.5pt}{1em}\selectfont CAE\vphantom{q}
}
\hfill
{
\ifnum \thedraw>0
DRAW \circled{\thedraw}
\fi
\ifnum \thepick>0
PICK \circled{\thepick}
\fi
}
\else
{\raggedleft
\ifnum \thedraw>0
DRAW \circled{\thedraw}
\fi
\ifnum \thepick>0
PICK \circled{\thepick}
\fi
}
\vcenteredhbox{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}
\vcenteredhbox{
    \fontsize{8.5pt}{1em}\selectfont Cards Against Equestria
}
\fi
\end{bottompar}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setmainfont{HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd}
\card{Zecora’s meth lab.}
\pagecolor{black}
\color{white}
\card[small=1, pick=2]{Today, Mayor Mare announced her official campaign position on \rule{50mm}{1pt} and \rule{50mm}{1pt}. No pony was the least bit surprised.}
\card{Twilight botched another spell… it’s started raining \rule{50mm}{1pt}.}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]